# Why does a Set Returning Function (SRF) run slower in a FROM clause?

Tags: postgresql, performance, functions, database-internals, set-returning-functions

**This is a database-internals question.** I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5, I'm wondering why Set Returning Functions (SRFs), also known as Table Valued Functions (TVFs) run slower when in a `FROM` clause, for instance when I execute these commands,

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,1e7);
SELECT 10000000
Time: 5573.574 ms
```

It's *always* substantially slower than,

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS SELECT generate_series(1,1e7);
SELECT 10000000
Time: 4622.567 ms
```

Is there a general rule that can be made here, such that we should *always* be running Set-Returning Functions outside of a `FROM` clause?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's start by comparing execution plans:

```
tinker=> EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,1e7);
                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Function Scan on generate_series  (cost=0.00..10.00 rows=1000 width=32) (actual time=2382.582..4291.136 rows=10000000 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.022 ms
 Execution time: 5539.522 ms
(3 rows)

tinker=> EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT generate_series(1,1e7);
                                           QUERY PLAN                                            
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=0.00..5.01 rows=1000 width=0) (actual time=0.008..2622.365 rows=10000000 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.045 ms
 Execution time: 3858.661 ms
(3 rows)
```

Okay, so now we know that `SELECT * FROM generate_series()` is executed using a `Function Scan` node, while `SELECT generate_series()` is executed using a `Result` node. Whatever is causing these queries to perform differently boils down to the difference between these two nodes, and we know exactly where to look.

One other interesting thing in the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output: note the timings. `SELECT generate_series()` is `actual time=0.008..2622.365`, while `SELECT * FROM generate_series()` is `actual time=2382.582..4291.136`. The `Function Scan` node *starts* returning records around the time the `Result` node *finished* returning records.

What was PostgreSQL doing between `t=0` and `t=2382` in the `Function Scan` plan? Apparently that's about how long it takes to run `generate_series()`, so I'd wager that's exactly what it was doing. The answer starts to take shape: it seems like `Result` returns results immediately, while it seems like `Function Scan` materializes the results and then scans them.

With the `EXPLAIN` out of the way, let's check the implementation. The `Result` node lives in [`nodeResult.c`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_10_STABLE/src/backend/executor/nodeResult.c), which says:

```
 * DESCRIPTION
 *
 *      Result nodes are used in queries where no relations are scanned.
```

The code is simple enough.

`Function Scan` lives in [`nodeFunctionScan.c`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_10_STABLE/src/backend/executor/nodeFunctionscan.c), and indeed it appears to take a [two phase execution strategy](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_10_STABLE/src/backend/executor/nodeFunctionscan.c#L87-L91):

```
/*
 * If first time through, read all tuples from function and put them
 * in a tuplestore. Subsequent calls just fetch tuples from
 * tuplestore.
 */
```

And for clarity, let's see [what a `tuplestore` is](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_10_STABLE/src/include/utils/tuplestore.h#L3-L17):

```
 * tuplestore.h
 *    Generalized routines for temporary tuple storage.
 *
 * This module handles temporary storage of tuples for purposes such
 * as Materialize nodes, hashjoin batch files, etc.  It is essentially
 * a dumbed-down version of tuplesort.c; it does no sorting of tuples
 * but can only store and regurgitate a sequence of tuples.  However,
 * because no sort is required, it is allowed to start reading the sequence
 * before it has all been written.  This is particularly useful for cursors,
 * because it allows random access within the already-scanned portion of
 * a query without having to process the underlying scan to completion.
 * Also, it is possible to support multiple independent read pointers.
 *
 * A temporary file is used to handle the data if it exceeds the
 * space limit specified by the caller.
```

Hypothesis confirmed. `Function Scan` executes upfront, materializing the function's results, which for large result sets results in spilling to disk. `Result` doesn't materialize anything, but also supports only trivial operations.